# How to automate download of webpage HTML? Access Denied

Tags: html, r, shell, web-scraping

I've tried a variety of utilities at the Mac command line (`curl`, `wget`) and in R (`rvest`, `download`, `RCurl`) to get the equivalent of `File > Save Page As ... > Webpage, Complete` in Chrome. All of these utilities do *something*, but none of them produce the same results as the menu-driven approach in Chrome, which does capture all the information I need from the webpage. I need to download and parse the HTML for many, many webpages.

I'm not sure whether there is something special about the webpages I'm trying to download, or if I'm just not working with the right utilities. Often I'm getting Access Denied.

Comment: The page from dnb.com is application page, with large number of included javascript. You will not be able to retrieve it using page extraction tool (curl, wget). Consider using headless chrome, or try to find an API that you call

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the website I'm trying to scrape denies access under a number of known scraper-like methods. Thanks to dash-o for pointing me to headless Chrome. Using headless, you can automate downloads of the DOM, which contains all the relevant info. However, headless is detectable through the User Agent. All you have to do is pass a standard browser User Agent as an argument to headless Chrome to spoof a standard browser:

`chrome --headless --dump-dom --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36" https:// ...`

See these for more details:
https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#printing_the_dom